# MySQL adds column name to beginning of the result

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Hopefully this is just quick fix, but when I execute any select query, such as,

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM table_info 
WHERE load_order IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY load_order;
```

it always prepends the column name to the result. In this case, the result is,

```
table_name settings tax tax_rate sales_tax_zone sic 
naics exempt_reason wh pack pcat route supply_point 
point credit_status fuel_type participant site salesman 
driver truck profit terms vendor product pump customer 
card card_fuel_type tax_certificate prodware prodware_price
```

Here is a snippet from the bash script:

```
TABLES=` (
  echo -n "select table_name from table_info "
  echo -n "where load_order is not null "
  echo "order by load_order;" 
) | mysql -uuser -ppassword database`
```

Parsing it via:

```
for TABLE in ${TABLES}
do
if [ $TABLE != 'table_name' ]
    do_table #Start the load process
fi
done
```

The problem is the script is quite large (~2000) lines and there are many select queries. Is there an option I can pass to mysql that will exclude the column name?

**Found the solution: I needed to use the --skip-column-names option when invoking mysql. Thanks for all the answers.**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "search criteria" which is displayed as the first row?

Comment: Search criteria being the fields I wish to select. In this case, table_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like that's the column name coming back in your result set.

To deal with this from your shell script, try modifying the code that's handling the results. Somehow skip the first result, as it's the name of the column.

Pseudocode:

```
for each result in myResultSet
    if result != myResultSet[0]
    begin
        //include this result.
    end
next
```

Comment: Yes that is the problem and I am running it via a shell script.

Comment: @btl: please edit your question with the script, and how you're parsing the results.

Comment: This is essentially what I need, but I found out the --skip-column-names option does exactly what I need when invoking mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to your question:

The mysql CLI man page says that there's an option for "--column-names".  Try that.

And here's the answer to the question you didn't ask:

Yes, you should be doing it another way.  Drop into some language that actually gives you a database connection rather than running "many select queries" via pipes!

Comment: I wish I had the luxury of using another language, unfortunately this is based in a legacy system, so I'm stuck with what I have. Thank you for the reply about the option, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the select to read

```
SELECT table_name as ` ` 
FROM table_info 
WHERE load_order IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY load_order;
```

or

```
SELECT table_name as `\0` 
FROM table_info 
WHERE load_order IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY load_order;
```